# How do I draw the graph of inequalities in the coordinate plane?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to graph the following inequalities (done in desmos) in latex.
I need the code.
[image: Inequalities]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit (1):** After editing a question and discussion in comments, the question is more clear now. Also you provide solution for the first image (thank you!), so below is now  complete MWE (Minimal Working Example) with all images with description how they are drawn. If you need only images, you can simply extract them from MWE.

**Edit (2):** In MWE are added short explanation how the images are drawn. Also are defined new commands by which image codes are shortened.

Since you are novice here, let mi give you some starting point for solve your problem:

- If you use LaTeX, than is very recommended to use its syntax at writing math. `$$` is TeX switch to math environment (or out from it to text). In LaTeX is for this purposed define `\[` ... `\]` or `\begin{equation*}` ... `\end{equation*}`.
- For drawing diagrams is `pgfplots` package seems to be better choice than use pure `tikz` (to be honest, this depends on how familiar you are with any of them).
- Beside those packages are also available `pstricks` and others.

Based on my guessing that you like to write your assignment in form *task* - *solution*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17, 
     %%%% common settings
     axis lines=middle,  
     axis line style= {-Straight Barb},
     axis on top,
     x=7mm, y=3.5mm, % <---
     %
     xlabel=$x$,
     xlabel style=right,
     xmin=-4.5, xmax=4.5,
     xtick={-4,-3,...,\Xmax}, % <---
     %
     ylabel=$y$,
     ylabel style=above,     
     ymin=-8.5, ymax=4.5,
     ytick={-8,-7,...,8},
     %
     tick style=black,
     tick label style = {inner sep=1pt, font=\tiny},
     %
     no marks,
     every axis plot post/.append style={draw=teal, very thick}
             }
% abbreviations for use of axis minimal and maximal values
     \newcommand\Xmin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}
     \newcommand\Xmax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}
     \newcommand\Ymin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}
     \newcommand\Ymax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
For all images followed are determined global settings with \verb+\pgfplotsset+ in document preamble. Where is needed, they are  overwritten by local defined options, for example with changed minimal and maximal axis size, size of axis units etc. This changes are described where are done.

Each images has three parts:
    \begin{enumerate}
\item   With \verb+\addplot [name patrh=A]+ is drawn border line of the inequality area. Their position is determined by two (or three) coordinates, which are calculated from given inequalities.
\item   With \verb+\path [name path=B]+ is drawn invisible auxiliary line at bottom or right site of images, which is needed at coloring area of validity of inequality
\item   Width \verb+\addplot [teal!30] fill between [of=A and B]+ is colored area of validity of given inequality.
    \end{enumerate}

Tasks are:
    \begin{enumerate}
\item   Sketch the inequality shown below on the coordinate axes:
\[
y \leq -3: 
\]
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [name path=A] coordinates { (\Xmin,-3) (\Xmax,-3) };

\path [name path=B] (\Xmin,\Ymin) -- (\Xmax,\Ymin)
    node[above left, font=\footnotesize, text=black] {$y \leq 3$};
\addplot [teal!30] fill between [of=A and B];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\item   Sketch the inequality shown below on the coordinate axes:
\[
y > 3x - 3
\]
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [name path=A] coordinates { (\Xmin,-15) (\Xmax,9) };

\path [name path=B] (\Xmax,\Ymin)
    node[above left, font=\footnotesize, text=black] {$y\leq 3x-3$}
                                  -- (\Xmax,\Ymax);
\addplot [teal!30] fill between [of=A and B];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\item   Sketch the inequality shown below on the coordinate axes:
\[
x \geq 2y + 2
\]
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [name path=A] coordinates { (-15,\Ymin) (19,\Ymax) };

\path [name path=B] (\Xmin,\Ymin) -- (\Xmax,\Ymin)
    node[above left, font=\footnotesize, text=black] {$x \geq 2y + 2$};
\addplot [teal!30] fill between [of=A and B];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\item   Sketch the region on a coordinate plane:
\[
x^2 + y^2 > 16
\]
Above inequality is fulfilled in outside of circle $x^2+y^2=r^2=16$. Drawing this parametric function with \verb+pgfplots+ is done in two steps: with arcus above $x$-axis and arcus below it. Coloring of the inequality region require to use two layers: background layer (\verb+main+) for drawing circle and layer above it (\verb+pre-main+) for coloring  (see image code for this item).

For see circle as circle, it is necessary to use the same units on both axis, if  \verb+x=7mm+ (set in \verb+\pgfplotsset+) then we need now set \verb+y=7mm+. By this image become (to much) taller, so at the same time it is sensible to reduce minimal and maximal value for $y$-axis:
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
%   used is layered drawing                                     %
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\[
    \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}
\begin{axis}[y=7mm,       % <--
             ymin=-4.5,   % <--
             samples=101]

\addplot [name path=A, domain=-4:4] {+sqrt(16-x^2)};
\addplot [name path=B, domain=-4:4] {-sqrt(16-x^2)};

\pgfonlayer{pre main}
% coloring of plane
\fill[teal!30]  (\Xmin,\Ymax) -| (\Xmax,\Ymin)
node[above left, text=black] {$x^2 + y^2 > 16$} 
                              -| cycle;
% coloring of circle
\addplot [white] fill between [of=A and B];
\endpgfonlayer
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\item   Sketch the region on a coordinate plane:
\[
y > |x-2|
\]
That symmetry of this inequality, which is at $x=2$, can be easy to observe.  the \verb+\xmin+ and \verb+xmax+ is increased for 2:
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2.5, xmax=6.5, 
             ymin=-4.5] % reduce height of image
\addplot [name path=A] coordinates { (\Xmin,4.5) (2,0) (\Xmax,4.5) };

\path [name path=B] (\Xmin,\Ymin) -- (\Xmax,\Ymin)
    node[above left, font=\footnotesize, text=black] {$y=|x-2|$};
\addplot [teal!30] fill between [of=A and B];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Upworkyasir, Well, the answer is not just "info" but contains solutions to most of your problems (which we still don't know exactly what they are). What is obstacle that you not do this? In my answer I show you you three examples, which can serve as skeletons to the other two. Try to draw this two yourself. With this you will learn about pgfplots and as well about LaTeX

Comment: I have edited my post to include 5 images that I have drawn in Desmos. I need the exact graphs in latex code. I hope you understand what my question is, now..

Comment: @Upworkyasir, I'm aware about, let me say, at least for half of your problems, the second half I can't see if you solve them, since your link is not available. Please copy (screenshot) of those image to the question, that they will be simple visible to all. members of site.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: First image is the line y = -3 and the region less than that. So, the first inequality graph is correct.
Also, i would need to code the graphs in latex, that's the requirement.

This is what i got, which isn't correct:
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [name path=A] coordinates { (-4,-3) (4,-3) };


\path [name path=B] (-4,-8.5)
   node[above left, font=\footnotesize, text=black] {$y\leq -3$}
                            -- (4,-8.5);
\addplot [teal!30] fill between [of=A and B];
\addplot [teal!30] fill between [of=A and B];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

Comment: @Upworkyasir, (i) regarding the first image you are right, (ii) I'm glad to see, that you write correct code for the first image, (iii) in edited answer I provide complete MWE (Minimal Working Example) with codes for all images.

Comment: thank you so much.
Im trying to understand each pieces of code.

Comment: @Upworkyasir, I added some explanation to MWE, which hopefully will help you at understanding, how images ar drawn. Of course, for some details or to get bigger picture in drawing diagrams with `pgfplots` can help reading the packed manual and seeexamples on  http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/all/?page=4  as well here on site. Happy TeXing! BTW, if you will find answer helpful, you can accept it by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer :-).

Comment: thanks.
Just check marked it.
Can you take a look at:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575854/drawing-shaded-region-above-a-shifted-square-root-function