# Drawing shaded region above a shifted square root function

Tags: tikz-pgf, root

**EDIT 1**

I changed the code a bit. This code worked:

```
\addplot[name path=A,domain=-0.236:4.236, solid, blue] {sqrt(5-(x-2)^2)};

\addplot [name path=C, line width=0.05pt] coordinates { (-0.236,5) (4.236,5) };

\addplot [teal!20] fill between [of=A and C];
```

*disregard the watermark behind*

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am trying to graph this.
The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
            width=10cm,
            height=10cm,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            enlargelimits,
            xtick={-2, -1,...,5,6},
            ytick={-2,-1,...,3,4},
            domain=-2:6,
            samples=100,
            xmin=-2, 
            xmax=6,
            ymin=-2, 
            ymax=4,
            ]
            

\addplot[name path=B,domain=-2:6, dashed, blue, transparent] {4};
\addplot[name path=A,domain=-3:3, dashed, blue] {sqrt(x)};

\addplot [name = path=J, dashed, blue]coordinates {(1,6) (1,-6)};
\addplot[name path=H,blue,domain={-4:4}, solid, line width=1pt] {-5};

\addplot[red, fill opacity=0.20] fill between [of=B and A,soft clip= 
{domain=-\sqrt{5}+2:\sqrt{5}+2}];


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iu4V.png
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: I am using a custom .cls file from someone else. I really don't know which stuffs from preamble are needed for this piece of code to compile.
Can you help me out with the picture part please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,
             }
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=100mm, height=100mm,
     axis lines=middle,
     axis line style= {-Straight Barb},
     axis on top,
     grid=both,
     minor tick num=4,
     minor grid style={very thin},
     xlabel=$x$,
     ylabel=$y$,
     xmin=-0.5, xmax=4.5,
     ymin=-0.5, ymax=4.5,
     tick style=black,
     tick label style = {inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize},
     every axis plot post/.append style={draw=teal, very thick},
     no marks,
     samples=201,
            ]

\addplot [name path=A,domain=-5:5] {sqrt(4.84-(x-2)^2)};

\path    [name path=B] (-0.2,4.5) --  (4.2,4.5);
\addplot [teal!30] fill between [of=A and B,
        ];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, but the shaded region isn't expected.

Comment: @Upworkyasir, what is expected? I understood that you like to draw showed image. Please provide a sketch of expected result.

Comment: I used your code, but the image isn't as yours.
How to add screenshot in comment?

Comment: For this purpose I use Snipping Tool (I'm on windows machine) . By it copy image from screen and past it into answer or question. Compiling my MWE should give showed image. Tested again.

Comment: I too use Snipping Tool, but it doesn't paste on Comment.
Idk why but mine won't compile properly

Comment: No this work with question and answers, comments cannot contains images. There you can insert only a link to your image stored in some cloud. Show image in your question.

Comment: @Upworkyasir, thank you to accept my answer, but you can upvote too (by clicking on up-triangle at top left side of answer) :-)