# Tikz: Drawing Riemann zeta function on Complex Plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw the Riemann zeta function in the complex plane using `LaTeX` (with `TikZ`). I want to fill the convergent section of the graph with dashed lines or with color. I'm having a hard time trying to mimic the following sketch with `LaTeX`:

[image]

Would anyone be willing to tell me how, or provide me with some reference?

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575636/ can help you.

Comment: Thank you both! That is indeed helpful!